# plpgsql return column name and column stats as a table

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to use pgplpsql in a postgres database to:
- loop through all columns in a schema, and for every column that is double precision I want to return a table containing fields 'table name, column name, min value, max value, mean value, median value.

-So far I have managed to return the min, max, mean of these fields - but not in a table despite defining the table in the 'returns statement'.

Question: 
How do I return a table properly
How do I include the column name and table name for the columns within this table? I have tried many things with a full range of error messages.

Becky

```
DROP FUNCTION household.numeric_stats(schemanm text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION household.numeric_stats(schemanm text)
returns table(min double precision, max double precision, avg double precision)as $$

DECLARE
  cname text;
  tname text;

BEGIN
   for cname,tname in SELECT column_name::text col,table_name::text tble FROM information_schema.columns
   where table_schema = schemanm and data_type in ('double precision')
   and table_name::text not in ('ap_household','derived_forest_income', 'derived_product_income','derivedproduct_income','view_income_overview_by_household')

   LOOP

     RAISE NOTICE 'cname is: % from %', cname, tname;
     return query
     execute format('select min(%I), max(%I), avg(%I) from  %I.%I where %I != ''NaN''', cname, cname, cname, schemanm, tname, cname);

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION household.numeric_stats(schemanm text)
  RETURNS TABLE(tname text, cname text
              , min float8, max float8
              , avg float8, median float8) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR tname, cname IN
      SELECT table_name::text, column_name::text
      FROM   information_schema.columns
      WHERE  table_schema = schemanm
      AND    data_type = 'double precision'
      AND    table_name <> ALL ('{ap_household,derived_forest_income, derived_product_income,derivedproduct_income,view_income_overview_by_household}'::varchar[])
   LOOP
      -- RAISE NOTICE 'tname: %, cname: %', tname, cname;
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
      $f$SELECT $1, $2, min(%1$I), max(%1$I), avg(%1$I), median(%1$I)
         FROM   %2$I.%3$I
         WHERE  %1$I <> 'NaN'$f$, cname, schemanm, tname)
      USING tname, cname;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM household.numeric_stats('myschema');
```

You need to create the median aggregate functions before you can use it. Instructions in the Postgres Wiki:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median